# Best practice for shared model in razor pages

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Being relatively new to ASP.NET Core and Razor Pages, I'm still trying to become familiar with the best approach to handle certain logic.

I have a model that encapsulates every property or model I would liked to have readily available on every razor page.

As I have it now, I have a in-memory model called `CurrentEnvironment` with a few properties and objects that I'll access from various pages.

**CurrentEnvironment** Snippet:

```
public class CurrentEnvironment {
    public string Url {get;set;}
    public string IPAddress {get;set;}
    Public AppUser User {get;set;}\
    //.....
}
```

Each Razor Page implements `BasePageModel` which itself implements `PageModel`.  If the page requires Authentication, then there is a `SecurePageModel` with the `[Authorize]` filter that implements `BasePageModel`

**BasePageModel**:

```
public CurrentEnvironment CurrentEnvironment { get; set; } = new CurrentEnvironment();

public override Task OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync(PageHandlerExecutingContext context, PageHandlerExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        CurrentEnvironment.IPAddress = context.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString();
        CurrentEnvironment.Url = context.HttpContext.Request.GetDisplayUrl();


        return base.OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync(context, next);
    }
```

**SecurePageModel** snippet:

```
[Authorize]
    public class SecurePageModelAsync : BasePageModelAsync
    {

//...... 

public override Task OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync(PageHandlerExecutingContext context, PageHandlerExecutionDelegate next)
{
        CurrentEnvironment.User = _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User).Result;

        return base.OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync(context, next);
    }
}
```

**My question(s):**

1. Is there a better way to handle this and produce the same results?
2. I'm guessing I want to create a service to handle `CurrentEnvironment` maybe?  If so, how would I populate the service?  Middleware?